request to reopen a question
An answerer misunderstood my request for configuring a vlans on a cisco switch and closed my question as off topic. the answerer believed I was requesting assistance configuring a consumer device.
though the network topology includes consumer devices, I believe them to be configured correctly. my request is specifically about the cisco switch.
if my question is unclear, please help me understand what additional information I can add.
otherwise please restore the question to an answerable state.
Configuring a Cisco switch VLAN for WiFi guests

OK, let's try this - provided that is an on-topic business setup.
The 2970 has been out of support for a more than a decade, can't guarantee that the other moderators keep that question open.
